# Automated process Tabular Model Scripting Language (TMSL)

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I created my tabular model with SSAS and Now I'm looking for a solution to refresh it automatically.
So I have some questions :

could we process our tabular model with a stored procedure T-SQL calling the TMSL script ?

An example will be helpful

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2790/dynamic-xmla-using-tsql-for-sql-server-analysis-services/) explains how to setup a SQL Server linked server that connects to SSAS. Once that's done, you can run this:

```
declare @xmla varchar(max) = '
{
  "refresh": {
    "type": "full",
    "objects": [
      {
        "database": "YourDatabaseName"
      }
    ]
  }
}
';

exec (@xmla) at SSAS;
```

This approach lets you write some logic to execute different TMSL scripts daily. For example you could refresh only the current year partition.

If you want to execute a static script then a [SQL Agent job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-an-analysis-services-job-step?view=sql-server-2017&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-4020762) is another way to go.

Comment: I tested the execution with an SQL Agent Job and it works, it's an alternative solution of SQL Server linked server . Thank's !